# jmeter EOFException happens when go browsing with HTTP Server Proxy

Tags: java, jmeter, proxy-server

I'm using jmeter 2.9 with an HTTP Proxy Server with HTTP4 client and I've set all the proxy confs of my browser correctly but when I start the server proxy and go to browser I get the following output..

```
java.io.EOFException
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readUByte(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readUShort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.client.entity.GzipDecompressingEntity.decorate(GzipDecompressingEntity.java:56)
    at org.apache.http.client.entity.DecompressingEntity.getDecompressingStream(DecompressingEntity.java:68)
    at org.apache.http.client.entity.DecompressingEntity.getContent(DecompressingEntity.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity.getContent(BasicManagedEntity.java:89)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:299)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:62)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1088)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:211)
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show the full jmeter.log ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HTTPS your issue may be related to certificate issues.

JMeter 2.10 will be out in few hours (as of 19 october 2013) and simplifies HTTPS recording.

You could give it a try, download it, start it , in File Menu , select "Template..." and select Recording one.

It is configured to listen on port 8888, start proxy, it will generate a root CA certificate, a popup will appear giving you instructions on how to install it.

Install Root CA, configure proxy settings in it and start recording, everything should go fine.